# Lower bound for the trace of a product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let we have the estimate
$$
 {\rm tr}(P)\ge\gamma>0,
$$
where $P\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is positive-definite matrix.

Is it possible to obtain the nontrivial lower bound in terms of $P$ and $C$ for
$$
 {\rm tr}(CPC^{\rm T}),
$$
where $C\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and $m<n$?

The estimate
$$
 {\rm tr}(CPC^{\rm T})={\rm tr}(PC^{\rm T}C)\ge\lambda_{\max}(P)\cdot\lambda_{\min}(C^{\rm T}C)
$$
gives us the trivial zero bound only.

Comment: Not in terms of $\gamma$ and $C$. When $C$ is fat, $0$ is the infimum even if $\sigma_\min(C)$ is bounded away from zero. Consider $C=\pmatrix{I_m&0}$ and $P=tI_m\oplus\frac{\gamma-mt}{n-m}I_{n-m}$ for instance. We have $\operatorname{tr}(P)=\gamma$ but $\operatorname{tr}(CPC^T)=mt\to0$ as $t\to0^+$.

Comment: However, we do have a non-trivial lower bound in terms of $P$ (rather than $\gamma$) and $C$: $\operatorname{tr}(CPC^T)\ge\sigma_\min(P)\operatorname{tr}(CC^T)=\sigma_\min(P)\|C\|_F^2$.